# Notify Detached Thread on DLL_DETACHED

Tags: multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have the following code which creates a group of threads and detaches them immediately:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>

class TGroup final
{
private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;
    std::atomic_bool stop;

public:
    TGroup();
    ~TGroup();
    TGroup(const TGroup&) = delete;
    TGroup& operator = (const TGroup&) = delete;

    void terminate();
    void execute(std::function<void()> &&task);
};

TGroup::TGroup() : mutex(), condition(), tasks(), stop(false)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
    {
        std::thread([this] {
            while(true)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                condition.wait(lock, [this] {
                    return !this->tasks.empty() || this->stop;
                });

                if (this->stop)
                {
                    lock.unlock();
                    break;
                }

                auto task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
                this->tasks.pop();
                lock.unlock();

                task();
            }
        }).detach();
    }
}

TGroup::~TGroup()
{
    this->terminate();
}

void TGroup::terminate()
{
    if (!this->stop)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
        this->stop = true;
        lock.unlock();
        this->condition.notify_all();  //Causes a crash on Windows but not MacOS or Linux..
    }
}

void TGroup::execute(std::function<void()> &&task)
{
    if (!this->stop)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
        this->tasks.emplace(task);
        lock.unlock();
        this->condition.notify_one();
    }
}
```

In my `DLL_DETACHED` inside of `DLLMain`, I call `group.terminate()`. It works perfectly fine if I comment out `this->condition.notify_all();` in `TGroup.terminate()`.

Is there a reason that notifying the condition variable would cause a deadlock? It currently causes my process to NOT exit when I press the exit button (I have to use TaskManager to kill it).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program contains a data race on `*this`, between the `TGroup` object being destroyed, and an awoken thread trying to access `this->tasks` and other member variables. It therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

When you don't call `notify_all()`, you allow the operating system to kill sleeping threads as part of the normal process shutdown.